# toggleClass used to execute two different scrollTop methods, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop, toggleclass

So I have the following function running and it works great. The selected `div` expands with the `.slideToggle()` function and the page slides down the body with the `.animate()` and `.scrollTop()` methods.

```js
$('.pfitem').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('minimized maximized');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('minimized maximized');
        $(this).next().slideToggle(1200);            
        });

$('.pfitem.minimized').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
        }, 1200);            
        });
```

Now when I try to add this following code which from my understanding should slide the page back up to the `div` with an id of `#portfolio` it does nothing even though that now the class of the `div` that is targeted by the `.click()` function has been toggled to `.pfitem.maximized`, so the previous `.click()` function should not interfere.

```js
$(".pfitem.maximized").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#portfolio').offset().top
        }, 1200);
});
```

This is a snippet of my HTML, I have tried to strip it of irrelevant information (I am using bootstrap and have left some bootstrap classes in the code)

```html
<div class="page" id="portfolio">
    <div class="content container">
      
        <ul class="row npr">
            <li class="container col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 pfitem businesscards minimized">
                <div class="orangeover">
                    <span>Business Cards</span>
                </div>
            </li>
          
            <div class="container col-xs-12 maximizeitem minimized" id="businesscards">
                <div class="maxicontent col-sm-4">
                    <h4>BUSINESS CARDS</h4>
                        <p>Some text goes here</p>
                        <p>Some text goes here</p>
                </div><!-- maxicontent -->
                <div class="maxiimages col-sm-8">
                    <button class="close"><span class="">X</span></button>
                    <img src="" class="">
                </div><!-- maxiimages -->
            </div><!-- container maximizeitem -->
        </ul>
      
    </div><!-- .content .container -->
</div><!-- #portfolio -->
```

This is my first post, I hope I have provided sufficient information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the selectors to be evaluated dynamically you will have to use event delegation

```
$(document).on('click', '.pfitem', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('minimized maximized');
    $(this).next().toggleClass('minimized maximized');
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1200);
});

$(document).on('click', '.pfitem.minimized', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
    }, 1200);
});
```

Comment: might also be a good idea to include e.stopPropogation() to keep the event from bubbling up to the first click listener?

Comment: @deolectrix since we are binding the handler to document object.. there is no use of preventing the propogation

Comment: Thank you Arun! this solved my problem. I urge anyone that is having a similar issue has a read through [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click) which explains the difference between onclick and click